# Redefine List environment for tagged pdf

Tags: accessibility, tagged-pdf, lualatex-dev, tagpdf

I am trying to redefine the list environment, for auto tagging structure instead of manual tag in the tex file

I tried with the below coding

```
\AddToHook{env/enumerate/begin}{\tagstructbegin{tag=L}\tagmcbegin{tag=L}}
\AddToHook{env/enumerate/end}{\tagmcend\tagstructend}
\AddToHook{env/enumerate/itemize}{\tagstructbegin{tag=L}\tagmcbegin{tag=L}}
\AddToHook{env/enumerate/itemize}{\tagmcend\tagstructend}
\AddToHook{env/enumerate/description}{\tagstructbegin{tag=L}\tagmcbegin{tag=L}}
\AddToHook{env/enumerate/description}{\tagmcend\tagstructend}

\NewCommandCopy\olditem\item


\RenewDocumentCommand{\item}{o}
                     {\tagstructbegin{tag=LI}\tagmcbegin{tag=LI}%
                     \tagstructbegin{tag=Lbl}\tagmcbegin{tag=Lbl}%
                     \olditem%
                     \tagmcend\tagstructend%
                     \tagstructbegin{tag=LBody}\tagmcbegin{tag=LBody}
                     }
```

I am getting the wrong tag structure

how to close `\tagmcend \tagstructend` and reopen `\tagstructbegin{tag=LI}\tagmcbegin{tag=LI}                        \tagstructbegin{tag=Lbl}\tagmcbegin{tag=Lbl} \tagstructbegin{tag=Lbl}` for each item correctly

also tag `LI` not under the tag `L`, (see the below screenshot)

How to code the list structure to get the proper tag

[image]

MWE

```
\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase}
\DeclareDocumentMetadata{testphase=phase-II}
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tagpdf}
\tagpdfsetup{activate-all}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\AddToHook{env/enumerate/begin}{\tagstructbegin{tag=L}\tagmcbegin{tag=L}}
\AddToHook{env/enumerate/end}{\tagmcend\tagstructend}
\AddToHook{env/enumerate/itemize}{\tagstructbegin{tag=L}\tagmcbegin{tag=L}}
\AddToHook{env/enumerate/itemize}{\tagmcend\tagstructend}
\AddToHook{env/enumerate/description}{\tagstructbegin{tag=L}\tagmcbegin{tag=L}}
\AddToHook{env/enumerate/description}{\tagmcend\tagstructend}

\NewCommandCopy\olditem\item


\RenewDocumentCommand{\item}{o}
                     {\tagstructbegin{tag=LI}\tagmcbegin{tag=LI}%
                     \tagstructbegin{tag=Lbl}\tagmcbegin{tag=Lbl}%
                     \olditem%
                     \tagmcend\tagstructend%
                     \tagstructbegin{tag=LBody}\tagmcbegin{tag=LBody}
                     }



\begin{document}

para text para text para text
\begin{enumerate}
\item `substantially lessen competition' 

\item `every contract, combination'

\item `every person who shall monopolize'  is also coded separately).
\end{enumerate}

para text para text para text
\begin{enumerate}
\item[(a)] `substantially lessen competition' 

 `substantially lessen competition' 

\item[(b)] `every contract, combination'

\item[(c)] `every person who shall monopolize'  is also coded separately).
\end{enumerate}

para text para text para text
\begin{description}
\item  `substantially lessen competition' 

 `substantially lessen competition' 

\item  `every contract, combination'

\item  `every person who shall monopolize'  is also coded separately).
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you are missing a lot of `\tagstructend` commands. E.g. you are opening a LI but never close it.   This is not trivial to automate, as the second \item must do things differently than the first item. But we have a working prototype for list tagging. If you wait a few weeks, phase-II will do it automatically.